# RTSP to HTTP Live Streaming (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, ffmpeg, streaming

I have RTSP feed coming from my IP Camera as my source input and need to publish it to HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) for playback on iOS devices. I have already tried RTSP-to-RTSP on iOS and it worked; this time I want to try RTSP-to-HLS. I already have Wowza and ffmpeg installed but I just don't know what commands I should run to produce HLS. I've googled for the right commands but I just couldn't find them. What should I run?

Safari supports HLS. Does it also mean that  UIWebView supports HLS as well?

Comment: AVPlayer and safari supports HTTP streaming if you want to create HLS content then you can you use mediafilesegmenter.